# Cannot install OpenSSH on Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine (KVM)

Tags: server, ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am having trouble installing OpenSSH server on Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 which is a virtual machine using KVM.

When I try to install openssh-server I get the following response:

```
Setting up openssh-server (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Creating SSH2 RSA key; this may take some time ...
2048 SHA256:i6IKfykW1E9hYmlHFLid3KksBI11oxCmKlbQjFOVNZY root@host (RSA)
Creating SSH2 DSA key; this may take some time ...
1024 SHA256:tGZN8I6qfTdAanbPy4fxj/ARLTPrrtQKWZXTQZWG/o4 root@host (DSA)
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...key_generate failed

dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dpkg` scripts failed to generate the ECDSA keys for some reasons. The other host keys are generated successfully and your `ssh` server was installed successfully so you should not have any problem using it.

If you have problems, try to start the `ssh` service and check its logs:

```
# systemctl start ssh
# journalctl -b -e
```

Comment: I was getting some other errors when trying to start ssh so I thought they were related to the installation errors. I looked again at them as separate issues and resolved them and now everything is working correctly. Many thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was upgrading to openssh-server (1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8).

I got the following error.

```
Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ...unknown key type ecdsa
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have to edit /var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-server.postinst and comment the following lines.

```
#create_key "Creating SSH2 ECDSA key; this may take some time ..." \
#       "$hostkeys" /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -t ecdsa
#create_key "Creating SSH2 ED25519 key; this may take some time ..." \
#       "$hostkeys" /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key -t ed25519
```